# Colours of the legend items in ggplot2 not linked to my dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

As per title, my problem in ggplot2 is that the colours of the legend are not linked to the ones displayed on the map.

I have a variable which is a map of Europe:

```
# Create a map of Europe
eu_base <- qmap(location = "Cologne, Germany", zoom = 4, color = "bw", extent = "panel")
```

Then I have a dataframe with 3 columns: lat, long, and value (duration) called `TimeOverdf`. 
I then create discrete values of the column `value` within the `TimeOverdf` variable:

```
# I create a variable with the breaks
brk<-unique(c(1,seq(10,max(TimeOverdf$value),10),max(TimeOverdf$value)))

# Create a column on my dataframe with discrete values
TimeOverdf$value_discrete <- cut(TimeOverdf$value, breaks=brk, include.lowest=T)
```

when I then create my plot with discrete values and colours:

```
eu_base +
  geom_point(data = TimeOverdf, aes(x = lon, y = lat, colour = value_discrete),
             alpha = 0.01) +
  scale_colour_manual("Duration",
                      values = colorRampPalette(c("blue", "yellow", "red"))(length(brk)-1), 
                      breaks=waiver())
```

The colours of the legend items are all grey and seem not linked to the colours I specify in `scale_colour_manual`. I have the impression they are linked to the `eu_base` map. How can I get the colors in the legend to be consistent with those on the plot?

Comment: Your `alpha` is too low. You should see your colors if you change it back to `alpha = 1`

Comment: Vlo, thanks a lot. I can see the colours now. However now I have another problem. I would like the colours of the points to be transparent in the map otherwise I cannot see the underlying map of Europe. But at the same time in the legend they should be clearly visible. Any suggestion?

Comment: Add `guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))` Added as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))`

Comment: IT WORKED. You have my eternal gratitude.